# How to calculate first instance of running total where number is greater than x?

Tags: sql, sap-iq

```
EMPL_ID   MTH RUNNING_TOTAL_SALES 

a         1   $75
a         2   $225     
a         3   $325  
a         4   $375 
b         1   $325 
b         2   $335
b         3   $385
b         4   $380
```

I want to create a new column that determines that's the first month where total running sales exceed $300.  For instance, it would show 3 where EMPL_ID = 'a' and 1 for EMPL_ID = 'b'.  I am new sum over and partition by, which I used to calculate the running total of sales from sales, and I am not sure if I use this again for this new column...

Answer (score 0):

You can use more window functions:

```
with t as (<your query here>)
select t.*,
       min(case when RUNNING_TOTAL_SALES  > 300 then mth end) over (partition by empl_id) as first_month_over_300
from t;
```